# Correct Syntax for an SPF record

Tags: dns, spf

I'm about to create an TXT SPF record and I just want to make sure I have the correct syntax.

We send emails from our webserver, mail server, gmail & amazon SES

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com include:52.??.??.??? include:62.??.???.?? include:amazonses.com ~all
```

Obviously I have not put in the actual IP address' of our servers.

I see some people recommend that you use `~all` rather than `-all` as recommended by [amazon here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For specific ip-addresses you need to use the ip4 mechanism, so your record should look like this:

```
 v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:aspmx.googlemail.com ip4:52.??.??.??? ip4:62.??.???.?? include:amazonses.com ~all
```

It can also be argued that you should move the addresses most often used for sending mails to the start of the record, since that most often will make the SPF check terminate faster.

And regarding `-all` against `~all`, then the Amazon article describes is quite well. If you are 100% sure that mails from your domain will never be sent from addresses outside the SPF record, use `-all`, else use `~all`

Answer (score 1):

Stick with the `-all`, I'm not sure why you need the ip4's - unless you're sending from different webservers that have a different a record. Once you set it up just test it by sending emails to [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/)

webserver = a

mail server = mx

gmail = include:_spf.google.com

amazon SES = include:amazonses.com

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com -all
```